# Overridden functions for IAccessible interface do not work in cwnd-drived class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, accessibility, cwnd

I have a `CWnd`-derived class named button, and want to use `CWnd` accessibility functions, I  override this function in my class:

```
virtual HRESULT get_accName(VARIANT varChild, BSTR *pszName);
virtual HRESULT get_accChildCount(long *pcountChildren);
virtual HRESULT get_accDefaultAction(VARIANT varChild, BSTR *pszDefaultAction);
virtual HRESULT get_accDescription(VARIANT varChild, BSTR *pszDescription);
virtual HRESULT get_accKeyboardShortcut(VARIANT varChild, BSTR *pszKeyboardShortcut);
virtual HRESULT get_accParent(IDispatch **ppdispParent);
virtual HRESULT get_accRole(VARIANT varChild, VARIANT *pvarRole);
virtual HRESULT get_accState(VARIANT varChild, VARIANT *pvarState);
virtual HRESULT get_accValue(VARIANT varChild, BSTR *pszValue);
```

When I run the program, and set break a point in implementation of any of these functions, program does not enter these functions, and instead uses parent function, can any help me?

implementation of get_accName:

```
HRESULT Button::get_accName(VARIANT varChild, BSTR *pszName)
{
   //*pszName = SysAllocString(lpstrTitle);
   return S_OK;
}
```

I call `EnableActiveAccessibility()` in constructor of this class, but does not work yet.

Comment: When I override the get_accName method in IAccessible Interface for a combo Box in a dialog based MFC application, the method gets executed. But when it is overridden for other standard controls like Button, Edit, Checkbox the execution does not get there.

Comment: Don't you pretend to use `get_accValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
class CWnd {
  virtual HRESULT  get_accChildCount(long *pcountChildren);
};

class Button : public CWnd {

  virtual HRESULT  get_accChildCount(long *pcountChildren) {

    HRESULT childCount = CWnd:get_accChildCount(long *pcountChildren);

    //you can use the value from the ancestor class if it is of any use 
    //to you or add your own code 
    childCount = 1234;

    return childCount;
  } 
};
```

Comment: When a _"Button"_ class is inherited from _"CButton"_, the _"get_accName"_ not execute.

Answer (score 0):

You may be invoking these overriden methods incorrectly. Try renamed overriding. It can make things clearer and point out if anything is wrong. See below for an example implementation.

```
ref class Base
{
public:    
    virtual void Boo()
    {
        Show("Base::Boo");
    }    
};

ref class Derived : Base
{
public:    
    //Overrides Base::Boo
    virtual void Woo() = Base::Boo
    {
        Show("Derived::Woo");
    }
};
```

Invoke it like:

```
void _tmain()
{ 
    Base* r = new Derived();

    Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(r);
    d->Woo();
}
```

From [CodeProjects](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7498/Function-overriding-in-C-CLI)